# PYTHON Sockets and structure

Tags: python

Is there any way of converting the python socket object to a void pointer. I am using ctypes and I have tried using cast and the conversion functions of python.

I am also using a DLL and there is a function which takes structure as its argument.
But when i pass the structure to the function I am getting invalid parameters as error.
Is there any drawback in using python for C DLL's created on C which take C type parameters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Socket Programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547895/socket-programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good reason to convert a socket to a pointer. You can use `socket.fileno()` to get the socket's file descriptor which should be usable in C code.

If your library expects a pointer, you might need to wrap it with a ctypes struct - but without knowing details we can't tell.

Comment: The Library actually accepts a pointer to a pointer to a void. In C it is easy to dereference pointers. The C function is ->            long UNILIB_CALL UL_cbOpen ( void **psocket, char * ipAddress, unsigned int port, int connectionTimeout, int sendTimeout, int recvTimeout).   UNILIB_CALL is __stdcall.   This is a call back function.    The Python Code is here->      libc=WinDLL("Unilib.dll");
    ulopen=WINFUNCTYPE(c_long,POINTER(c_void_p),c_char_p,c_uint,c_int,c_int,c_int);   Function   declaration is this   UL_cbOpen(psocket,ipAddress,port,connectionTimeout,sendTimeout,recvTimeout):